# Postgres in-filter complexity

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT var_2 
FROM table_a 
WHERE var_1 IN (<Large list of values>);
```

Lets say table_a has `n` rows and the large list of values is of length `t`, whcih is less than n. What is then the complexity of this query? `O(n), O(n*log(t)) or O(n*t)` I'm using postgres 10.

Comment: Why do you care? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Is the query to slow? Do you have an index on `var_1` (which is a *column* not a "var" btw)

Comment: I want to optimize my queries in general and I see this pattern many times. So I'm interested in how postgres handles requests like this. Because if it can solve it in O(n) times I don't have to think more about it, but otherwise I should consider writing improved queries. Furthermore I want to understand postgres query optimization better.

Comment: Optimizing a query always starts with looking at the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization. What is optimal is one one scenario is likely to be sub-optimal in another.  Don't optimize until there is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, rewriting a large IN list to a JOIN against a VALUES list, creates the better execution plan.

So a query like this:

```
select column_2
from the_table
where column_1 in (1,2,3,4);
```

**If the list does not contain duplicate values**, the above can be rewritten to:

```
select t.column_2
from the_table t
  join ( 
    values (1),(2),(3),(4)
  ) as v(c1) on v.c1 = t.column_1
```

To find out, *if* that improves the query, you will have to check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

Comment: I often use the values list as well, but I think it's worth mentioning that duplicate values in a values list will cause duplicates in the results, unlike duplicates in the IN clause.

Comment: @Jeremy, that's why I wrote "*If the list does not contain duplicate values*"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.